# How to get started with this project?

Tags: javascript, python, automation

I recently finished my C++ programming class, and I'll start school in september. There is a limited online Parking spot registration and it always gets filled very quickly.

I would like to create a code that will quickly access the page and register for me.

The question is, how is this feasible? I guess I could use python, or Javascript, but I have no idea how to go on from my C++ class. What should I learn/do to program this code?

EDIT:
I posted this question on other forums also and I've been receiving a lot of answers like this: you need to use the library ...

Sorry if I'm a noob, but I've never used library and I have trouble understanding it. Is it like #include like the library will give me access to many functions by doing #inlude?

Comment: There are good chances that the system will be protected against automated registrations via, say, a captcha. But if that is not the case, start reading up on how to program HTTP in your language. The registration will very likely be an HTML form, which you can simulate by sending an HTTP POST request with appropriate parameters (for that, you'll need to have a look at the actual HTML page that shows the registration form)

Comment: I don't recall a captcha from the website.
But thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to profile the existing behaviour. Try installing fiddler, register normally. That should show you all the traffic that is passed between you and the site.

Second step is to emulate that behaviour. All modern languages support sending HTTP requests. You might find it simpler in a higher level language like JavaScript.

Comment: Usually all you need to inspect/hack this is Chrome and ctrl+shift+i to open it's console...

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, it involves sending the right [HTTP POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request at the right time, and parsing the result to make sure it got submitted correctly.  You can do that with C++, although it would probably be easier in python if you already knew python.

The problem is, you have no way of testing the bot until the site goes live every semester, and no way of guaranteeing they won't change things between semesters.  And trust me, they will make changes to avoid bots hammering the site.  That's assuming they aren't already using captchas.  And if you accidentally break things, you will incur the wrath of the school administration.

My advice is to set an alarm for when registration opens and be ready in front of a web browser.